# How can I optimize syncing text inputs between users, when using socket.io?

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, socket.io

I am syncing a text input between a number of users, using [socket.io](http://socket.io/). The syncing is done, but, because I'm emitting character-by-character; and, there is a lot of operations happening in the middle (React and Redux states are updating, etc.) the app becomes extremely slow and crashes very soon.

Is there any way to emit events, less frequently, retaining the smoothness; or, a way to skip a few of the events (on the receiving end), if the stack of unhandled ones becomes full? Was using Web Socket a mistake and should I switch up to WebRTC and just sync my server, every now and then?

Comment: Without any code example it isn't possible to answer this question

Comment: There is a lot of complexity involved with the code. The question asks for concepts, not specific code snippets.